# Почему метод функции конструктора не работает по отношению к другой функции?

Tags: javascript

Я хочу реализовать метод "heal" (target) в классе "Mage". Когда я реализую его в цикле, он не работает. В симуляции битвы лучник мечника и мечника лучника, волшебник должен восстанавливает здоровье лучника.

```js
         function Unit(maxHealth, basicDamage, type) {
        this._maxHealth = maxHealth;
        this._currentHeaalth = maxHealth
        this._basicDamage = basicDamage;
        this._type = type;
        /*method for showing the status of life, true if the "health" is greater
          than 0 and false if equal to or lower */
        this._isAlive = function() {
            return this._currentHeaalth > 0
        };
        this._getFormattedHealth = function() {
            /* a method that 
                    shows the level of health*/
            shows the level of health
            return this._currentHeaalth + '/' + this._maxHealth + ' HP';
        };
        /*a method that returns the base damage of the heroand damage to the
          weapon (if it is set)*/
        this._getDamage = function() {
            return (this.weapon ? this.weapon._getDamage() : 0)
            this._basicDamage;
        };
        this._kick = function(target) {
            /* The method of hitting 
                   the hero for the chosen purpose*/
            if (this._isAlive()) {
                target._currentHeaalth = Math.max(0, target._currentHeaalth -
                    this._getDamage());
            }
            return this;
        };
        /*method for showing all the characteristics of the hero and changes
          with them*/
        this.toString = function() {
            return "Type - " + this._type + ", is alive - " + this._isAlive() +
                this._getFormattedHealth() + ', hero current damage - ' +
                this._getDamage();
        }
    }
    }
    
    function Archer(maxHealth, basicDamage) {
        Unit.apply(this, arguments);
        this._type = "archer";
    }
    var archer = new Archer(50, 5);
    console.log(archer.toString());
    
    function Swordsman(maxHealth, basicDamage) {
        Unit.apply(this, arguments);
        this._type = "swordsman";
    }
    var swordsman = new Swordsman(100, 10);
    
    function Mage(maxHealth, basicDamage) {
        Unit.apply(this, arguments);
        this._type = "mage";
        this.heal = function(target) { /*a method of treatment that works when the 
                                         archer's health falls below his maximum health*/
            if (this._currentHeaalth < this._maxHealth) {
                target._currentHeaalth = Math.max(this._maxHealth,
                    target._currentHeaalth + 50);
            }
            return this;
        }
    }
    var mage = new Mage(40, 15);
    // cycle until someone dies
    while (archer._isAlive() && swordsman._isAlive()) {
        archer._kick(swordsman);
        mage.heal(archer);
        swordsman._kick(archer);
    }
    console.log(archer.toString());
    console.log(swordsman.toString());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас было некоторое количество ошибок, вот работающий код:

```js
function Unit(maxHealth, basicDamage, type) {
  this._maxHealth = maxHealth;
  this._currentHeaalth = maxHealth
  this._basicDamage = basicDamage;
  this._type = type;
  /*method for showing the status of life, true if the "health" is greater
    than 0 and false if equal to or lower */
  this._isAlive = function() {
    return this._currentHeaalth > 0
  };
  this._getFormattedHealth = function() {
    /* a method that 
            shows the level of health*/

    return this._currentHeaalth + '/' + this._maxHealth + ' HP';
  };
  /*a method that returns the base damage of the heroand damage to the
    weapon (if it is set)*/
  this._getDamage = function() {
    return (this.weapon ? this.weapon._getDamage() : this._basicDamage);
  };
  this._kick = function(target) {
    /* The method of hitting 
           the hero for the chosen purpose*/
    if (this._isAlive()) {
      target._currentHeaalth = Math.max(0, target._currentHeaalth -
        this._getDamage());
    }
    return this;
  };
  /*method for showing all the characteristics of the hero and changes
    with them*/
  this.toString = function() {
    return "Type - " + this._type + ", is alive - " + this._isAlive() + ' | ' +
      this._getFormattedHealth() + ', hero current damage - ' +
      this._getDamage();
  }
}

function Archer(maxHealth, basicDamage) {
  Unit.apply(this, arguments);
  this._type = "archer";
}
var archer = new Archer(50, 5);

function Swordsman(maxHealth, basicDamage) {
  Unit.apply(this, arguments);
  this._type = "swordsman";
}
var swordsman = new Swordsman(100, 10);

function Mage(maxHealth, basicDamage) {
  Unit.apply(this, arguments);
  this._type = "mage";
  this.heal = function(target) {
    /*a method of treatment that works when the 
                                            archer's health falls below his maximum health*/
    if (target._currentHeaalth < target._maxHealth) {
      target._currentHeaalth = Math.min(target._maxHealth,
        target._currentHeaalth + 50);
    }
    return this;
  }
}
var mage = new Mage(40, 15);
// cycle until someone dies

while (archer._isAlive() && swordsman._isAlive()) {
  archer._kick(swordsman);
  mage.heal(archer);
  swordsman._kick(archer);
}
console.log(archer.toString());
console.log(swordsman.toString());
```

Comment: но в случае, когда я форматирую функцию "_getDamage" с "return (this.weapon ? this.weapon._getDamage() : 0) + this._basicDamage;"
на Ваш вариант, тогда базовый урон перестает добавляться к урону от оружия (если оно задается)

Comment: Зачем Вам заменять на мой? Я лишь показал пример, что Вы дальше хотите модифицировать - Ваше право.